# How do you find the audio latency ? (Windows/OSX)

Tags: windows, macos, audio, latency, wasapi

I'm writing a music application, but I have no clue how applications such as Ableton/Cubase/etc find the audio latency of a system (do they ?) so they can compensate for time difference when recording/playing.
Meaning, the audio input latency (from mic to useable buffer) and the audio output latency (from a buffer to sound in speakers).

It seems more complex than just a matter of buffer size, since an internal chain of events occurs in-between the analogic audio and the digital data the software has access to.

Any idea how to (gu)estimate that ?

Answer (score 4):

**CoreAudio:**

```objectivec
property.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyLatency;
if ( AudioObjectHasProperty( id, &property ) == true ) {
    result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData( id, &property, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &latency );
}
```

**WASAPI:**

```cpp
IAudioClient::GetStreamLatency
IAudioClient*& captureAudioClient->GetStreamLatency( ( long long* ) &stream_.latency[mode] );
IAudioClient*& renderAudioClient->GetStreamLatency( ( long long* ) &stream_.latency[mode] );
```

**ASIO:**

```c
long inputLatency, outputLatency;
ASIOGetLatencies( &inputLatency, &outputLatency );
```

**ALSA:**

```c
snd_pcm_sframes_t frames;
snd_pcm_delay( handle, &frames );
```

**OpenSL:**

```java
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
Method m = am.getClass().getMethod("getOutputLatency", int.class);
latency = (Integer)m.invoke(am, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

see also:

```
uint32_t afLatency;
android::AudioSystem::getOutputLatency(&afLatency, ANDROID_DEFAULT_OUTPUT_STREAM_TYPE);
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/media/+/4f924ff768d761f53db6fa2dbfb794ba7a65e776/opensles/libopensles/android_AudioPlayer.cpp
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/006ceacb82f62a22945c7702c4c0d78f31eb2290/media/libmedia/AudioSystem.cpp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the output is the same as input, with a delay.

If you find the FFT of the input signal and the output one, at the same time, both must to be the very similar of the input.

Make a correlation of both signals, and you must find a pulse.
More tall and thin pulse, more similar input and output.

The time from 0 to the pulse, is the delay time between signals.

The correlation of the FFT of the same signal is a pulse at 0.

The correlation of the FFT of the same signal delayed 1 seg is a pulse at 1s.
So on

Check this link
https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/26.php

Comment: "the output is the same as input, with a delay" what do you mean ? there's no way the output buffers I'm given to feed are the same as the input buffers I receive. I see no reason why they would share data.

Comment: latency is the amount of time between the input and the output of an audio signal.
supose, I talk to mic and I hear my voice in speaker.
if you have the input audio signal, and the output audio signal, you can know the latency by this way i said.

Comment: supose you send a buffer to the speaker, and get a new buffer from mic. Obviously the buffer are different.  , but the FFT of both signals are pretty similars.
The correlation of both give you something like a pulse and some noise. The noise is thee distortion, and the pulse is the match of the signals input and output. The delay latency is the shifting of the pulse.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. However I was looking more for a purely programmatic way to estimate latency, because I can't guarantee the user will use speakers (he can use headphones, thus no sound will filter back to the microphone). I guess DAWs such as Ableton or Cubase have other ways to estimate that.

Comment: Ok. Don't know in this way

Comment: I found two ways that seem to somehow answer what I'm looking for:

CoreAudio:
property.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyLatency;
  if ( AudioObjectHasProperty( id, &property ) == true ) {
    result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData( id, &property, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &latency );


WASAPI:
IAudioClient::GetStreamLatency
IAudioClient*& captureAudioClient->GetStreamLatency( ( long long* ) &stream_.latency[mode] );
IAudioClient*& renderAudioClient->GetStreamLatency( ( long long* ) &stream_.latency[mode] );